# Node js update based on JWT token

Tags: node.js, jwt

In Node js i try to update data to database

But i don't want to sent any id in paramenter instead of that i can take from token then i will update

this is my update code in controller

```
router.put('/', VerifyToken, function (req, res) {
    var token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.secret);
    User.findById(decoded.id, { password: 0 }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the user.");
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send("No user found.");
        var curtime = dateFormat(now, "HH:MM:ss"),
            curstatus = 'Test';
        const reportData = new Report({
            username: user.username,
            time: curtime,
            status: curstatus
        });
        Report.findByIdAndUpdate({ username : user.username},reportData)
            .then(report => {
                if (!report) {
                    return res.status(404).send({
                        message: "Report not found with Username " + user.username
                    });
                }
                res.send(report);
            }).catch(err => {
                if (err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
                    return res.status(404).send({
                        message: "Report not found with Username " + user.username
                    });
                }
                return res.status(500).send({
                    message: "Error updating report with Username " + user.username
                });
            });

    });

});
```

it always return this only  message: "Report not found with Username " + user.username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findByIdAndUpdate` finds documents by the `_id` field. See [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate).
The first parameter has to be the value of the `_id` field. `username` is not `_id`.

Try,

```
const reportData = {
   username: user.username,
   time: curtime,
   status: curstatus
}
Report.findOneAndUpdate({username : user.username}, reportData)
```

Comment: I got this error now "message": "Error updating report with Username test"

Comment: Can you log the error `err` inside the catch block and see what it says? Note that for find and update to work, a report with `username: test` must already exist.

Comment: yes it's a problem of id         "errmsg": "Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'",

Comment: Please try with my update. `reportData` must not be an instance of `ReportData`